# Runnable Jar File with extra .txt

Tags: java, user-interface, jar

I have built my GUI program and got a runnable jar file but I want to include a **txt file that can be edited** by the user to the jar file or accompanied with it. this text file can contain a path of an editor that is different between operating systems. Is there a way to do that?

thanks

Comment: Do you want to have it as a default for editing, or the changes should be saved too? If the former, you can use `ClassLoader#getResource()` or `ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream()` to load from the jar file. Else, I would recommend to create a Map with the locations for each OSes you want to support.

Comment: If an answer was helpful, you can [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235/227183).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to place the `.txt` (eg. `file.txt`) file  by the jar, i.e., you can access it in your Java code:

```
File file = new File("file.txt");
```

In another way, if you want to launches the associated editor application (default for that file type in the current OS) for editing, you can try the next:

```
File file = new File("file.txt");    
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    Desktop.getDesktop().edit(file);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you cant edit a file and save it inside the jar. what you can do is include your file in the jar with a default data, edit it and save it to a file outside the jar.

actually it is possible if you open the jar itself with the code, and repack it when you change the text, but its like disassemble a car doors, wheels, seats and engine just to put something in the glove box

Comment: Actually the repackaging might fail as in certain cases the jar might be referenced from the JVM and cannot be saved.

Comment: nope... when a jar runs, it extract its content to the system temp folder :)